# Use cases of makePrisms with examples

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

It's not clear to me the difference between makeLense and makePrisms?

I'm aware that when we want to access a nested structure/data then use makeLense like this:

```
data Point = Point { _x :: Int, _y :: Int}
data Test= Test {_name :: String, _position :: Point} 

makeLenses ''Point
makeLenses ''Test
```

Then we can access or modify the component of Test or Point. For instance, we define a function:

```
modify :: Test -> Test
modify = over (position . x) (*8)
```

So we can have:

```
let t1 = Test {_name= "Me", _position = Point {_x = 3, _y = 8}}
```

then

```
modify t1
```

would be:

```
Test {_name = "Me", _position = Point {_x = 24, _y = 8}}
```

**But, I don't know when and how to use makePrisms in the above example!**

Comment: Do you know the difference between a prism and a lens? If so, that is your answer. :)

Comment: @Alec No I don't know!

Comment: A prism essentially lets you check if something is of a specific form and, if it is, even edit it. Lens tend to be used with products and prisms with sums (co-products).

Comment: @Alec Thanks, can you please give me some examples using prisms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to understand this, you must understand types, type variables, algebraic data types (sum and product types) and you must also understand typeclasses and the `Functor` typeclass in particular. If you don't understand these things, bookmark this page, then go off and understand them, possibly with this resource that I helped work on for precisely this purpose, to illustrate and explain these basics: http://happylearnhaskelltutorial.com

So before we get to Prisms, you first need to know what a Lens is.

A `Lens` is often described as a functional getter/setter, but that's more about the implementation and so forth.

I'd like to try an experiment of description here with you now.

Say I have a page of very small text with some words on it. Now, I hand you a piece of cardboard the same size as that page, only it has hole for a magnifying glass set up to focus on a particular word. That word is in a specific place in that page.

So we have these two things: a page, and a magnifying glass "card" without a magnifying glass... if we put a glass in, it focusses on a particular place on the page. Now someone comes along with another page with different words on it, but in the same layout as the first page.

It's easy to image that you can take that card, put it on the new page and it will focus on the different word in that same place.

As well as a magnifying glass, you also have a special "eraser/printer" glass that when you put it into the card allows you erase and type words over that page.

So to now apply this to Lens, you can see with this example how if we take one piece of data (a page of text), a lens that fits that data (a card with a hole in it that matches the shape of the page) and a function that can "get" or "set" (or maybe other things) (that is, the magnifying glass or the eraser/printer glass, or other types of glasses), well, from this we can `view` the smaller piece of data (the word) in the larger piece of data (the page) to extract it... or perhaps we can `set` a different matching piece of data into the spot on that page...

`lens :: :: Functor f => (s -> a) -> (s -> b -> t) -> (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`

What does this function do? It **creates** a lens from some functions. Now we have the framework above to understand what a lens is, we can undertsand this function. I say to you that the `s` variable stands for "state" and it corresponds to the type of the piece of paper that is the context that the lens will focus within. Next I can say the `a` type variable corresponds to the word on the page that the lens will focus on. What about `b` and `t`? They are the transformed `a` and `s` values if we decide to change the value of the `a`, and that change changes its type.

What is the `Functor` for then? we'll find out in a while. Well, first up let's make a lens to make this practical. So, back to our `lens` function, its first argument is the "getter" function, the second argument is the "setter" function (hence the types). Then there's one other argument. Well, because Haskell functions are curried that's actually the return type: a function `s -> f t`. Let's make that lens now.

Let's say we have a list of values `[(1,(5,9)), (2,(3,6))]` and we'd like to make a lens that focusses on the second value in the second nested tuple. That's silly, though, because you could just use `snd . snd` right? Yeah, you could, so it's not a great example, but all the better examples are more complex, so bear with me - we'll get to them, and besides, can your `snd.snd` function also SET, or have a function applied to it? No, I didn't think so! :) (okay okay I know you could use `fmap (const val)` to set, but can it also change the type? well this line of thought is actually what you end up with Lens with if you continue it to its logical conclusion as Edward Kmett did - that's where the Functor comes in!)

`sndOfSndLens = lens (snd.snd) (\(x,(y,z)) newZ -> (x,(y,newZ)))`

So what did we get? we got a function of this type `sndOfSndLens :: Functor f => (a -> f t2) -> (t, (t1, a)) -> f (t, (t1, t2))`.

So let's get our values out: `map (view sndOfSnd) [(1,(5,9)), (2,(3,6))]` -> `[9,6]` Nice! That works... let's set new values in: `map (set sndOfSnd 2000) [(1,(5,9)), (2,(3,6))]` -> `[(1,(5,2000)),(2,(3,2000))]` okay fine...

If it was just getters or setters, that's boring, but there's also a function called `over` which will take a lens and a transforming function and run that transformation on the function of the focus of the lens... so let's subtract 10 from each: `map (over sndOfSnd (flip (-) 10)) [(1,(5,9)), (2,(3,6))]` -> `[(1,(5,-1)),(2,(3,-4))]` that's cool! well I'll let you read the rest of the lens documentation to understand all the other functions, because they're deep and lenses compose, and you can do all sorts of other things with them, too.

**Prism**

I promised we'd get to Prism, and look we're here... A Lens is a specific "optic" (while also, sometimes confusingly referring to the entire set of optics in total, too, so watch out for that), and Prism is another optic, thankfully completely specific. If a Lens is an optic that works for focussing on a particular part of a **product** *algebraic data type*, then a Prims does the same thing for **sum** types. That's why we were able to make a lens that talked about pairs (`(,)`) because they're a **product** type... that is they combine two types into one. Lens lets you focus on one piece, or a path through those pieces. By the way, our lens we created above can easily be defined by composing the more generic built in lenses: `_2 . _2`. There are also operator versions of all the lens functions we were talking about. They look pretty crazy, but they have a logic to them. Read up about them!

Prism lets you focus on one **path** through a **sum type**. What's a good example? Well, let's say we have think about the `Either` data type. It's `Either a b` where it's defined as `data Either a b = Left a | Right b`. So there's a corresponding `prism` function that lets us build a Prism the same as our above value. What happens if we use the built in `_Left` which focusses on the left side of an `Either`, but we only have a `Right 10` value? Let's see... but first, we should let you know that we can't use `view` any more because it might not work, so we need to use `preview` which will return a value that might **fail** (sorry, spoilers!):

`preview _Left (Left 10)` -> `Just 10` and then the `Right` one? `preview _Left (Right 10)` -> `Nothing`. Okay that's sweet.

The `set` function works fine, because it can fail silently if it doesn't make sense: `set _Left 30 (Left 10)` -> `Left 30`. What happens when it doesn't work? `set _Right 30 (Left 10)` -> `Left 10` that's right, nothing.

Cool... hopefully this explains Lenses and Prims. They're two really useful optics. The Lens library is **full** of them so I encourage you to look at them

**What about the original question tho?**

The original question was about `makeLenses` and `makePrisms`. These are template haskell expressions (that is, they're meta programming / similar to macros, but typed macros), and they let you automatically build your own lenses and/or prisms from your own data types. Hopefully it makes more sense now when you would pick one over the other and how they differ. This will give you at least an inkling into how they're different. To really understand, you should read the documentation and look up all the other functions and optics that are possible.

Welcome to the amazingly cool world of Lenses!

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer :) Do you cover Lenses in your book?

Comment: Can you please tell me why "uses" or "use" is used in monad? Specifically here in line 208 and 228:  https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/1f866450a8a530c119e3fc9edb84c97c56417aa2/lrc/Pos/Lrc/Fts.hs

Comment: That book is the first volume in a planned series that is taking a lot longer to produce than I would like. This is due to the fact that writing, editing and illustration takes a lot of time and energy and I want a better editor to help me do that, otherwise the boilerplate and admin work becomes huge so I'm having to write a better editor.

Comment: Because the book is the first volume, and it's an introductory volume, and it's focussed on beginning programmers, we don't cover lenses. It's aimed at people for whom Haskell is their first language. We plan to cover them in later volumes, but lenses are pretty advanced if you want to understand them well. One needs to have a good grip on all kinds of things before lenses make sense, or are even needed, as you can see from the first sentence of my answer to your question, above.

Comment: As to `use` or `uses`, I saw your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884171/haskell-use-or-uses-in-getter about this, but I think it's best to not hijack this question. I think someone gave you a reasonable answer there, if not a little terse. If you look through my answer here and learn it all, you'll be able to understand enough to answer the other question yourself, so maybe that's a good motivation.